# ExtentReport how to show all the test casses from test class in one raport?

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

When I run all test cases from test class, I am getting only one testcase result and other two are not displayed on the extent report. How can I get all test case results in one report?

```
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import pl.me.automation.config.WebDriverType;
import pl.me.automation.page.ContactPage;
import pl.me.automation.page.HomePage;
import pl.me.automation.utils.TestDataReader;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
```

I have a test class ContactPageTest:

```
public class ContactPageTest extends TestDataReader {
    private WebDriver webDriver;
    private HomePage homePage;
    private ExtentHtmlReporter reporter;
    private ExtentReports reports;
```

Does @BeforeEach and @AfterEach functions may be the reason why I'm are getting only the latest executed test result?
I've tried to create Base class for all the test cases with
@BeforeMethod@AfterMethod @BeforeTest and @AfterTest, but it didn't work either.

```
 @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        webDriver = WebDriverType.CHROME.create();
        webDriver.get("https://www.store.com");
        homePage = new HomePage(webDriver);
        homePage.clickCookie();
        reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("src//main//resources//reports//index.html");
        reports = new ExtentReports();
        reports.attachReporter(reporter);

    }

    @AfterEach
    public void destroy() {
        webDriver.close();
        reporter.flush();
        reports.flush();
    }
```

Three test cases I want to display in one raport:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldFillInAndSendForm() {
        reports.createTest("ContactPageTest - Fill in and send form");
        ContactPage contactPage = homePage.clickContact();
        contactPage.enterUserName(contact.getContactPageEnterUserName());
        contactPage.enterUserLastName(contact.getContactPageEnterUserLastName());
        contactPage.selectMessageSubject(contact.getContactPageSelectMessageSubject());
        contactPage.enterEmailAddress(contact.getContactPageEnterEmailAddress());
        contactPage.enterMessage(contact.getContactPageSelectMessageSubject());
        contactPage.clickSendMessageButton();
        assertTrue(contactPage.isContactMessageDisplayed());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendEmptyForm() {
        reports.createTest("ContactPageTest - Send Empty Form");
        ContactPage contactPage = homePage.clickContact();
        contactPage.clickSendMessageButton();
        assertTrue(contactPage.isEmailValidationErrorDisplayed());
        assertTrue(contactPage.isNameValidationError());
        assertTrue(contactPage.isMessageValidationError());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendFormWithIncorrectEmail() {
        reports.createTest("ContactPageTest - Send Form With Incorrect Email");
        ContactPage contactPage = homePage.clickContact();
        contactPage.enterUserName(contact.getContactPageEnterUserName());
        contactPage.enterUserLastName(contact.getContactPageEnterUserLastName());
        contactPage.selectMessageSubject(contact.getContactPageSelectMessageSubject());
        contactPage.enterEmailAddress(contact.getContactPageEnterIncorrectEmailAddress());
        contactPage.enterMessage(contact.getContactPageEnterMessage());
        contactPage.clickSendMessageButton();
        assertTrue(contactPage.isEmailValidationErrorDisplayed());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this issue. I added @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class ContactPageTest extends Forms {
    private WebDriver webDriver;
    private HomePage homePage;
    private ExtentHtmlReporter reporter;
    private ExtentReports reports;
```

And than  @BeforeAll,   @BeforeEach @AfterEach,  @AfterAll annotation

```
   @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        webDriver = WebDriverType.CHROME.create();
        webDriver.get("https://www.store.com");
        homePage = new HomePage(webDriver);
        homePage.clickCookie();

    }

    @BeforeAll
    public void TearUpReporter(){
        reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("src//main//resources//reports//index.html");
        reports = new ExtentReports();
        reports.attachReporter(reporter);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void destroy() {
        webDriver.quit();
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void tearDownReporter(){
        reporter.flush();
        reports.flush();
    }
```